# Change R to UTC

Tags: r, timezone, debian

I want to change Sys.timezone in R to UTC. Actually I have it on "Europe/Madrid".

To change it, I have tried changing Debian distribution with

```
 sudo vim /etc/timezone
```

And there change Europe/Madrid to UTC.

After that I have restart Debian and check Sys.timezone() in R, but still apears Europe/Madrid.

I also have tried with

```
 Sys.setenv(TZ='GMT')
```

But it does not work

How can I solve this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: try `Sys.setenv(TZ = "UTC")`

Comment: I have tried, but not working for me. Thanks!

Comment: Put `Sys.setenv(TZ = "UTC")` to the first line of the file `.Rprofile`. If you put it too late, `Sys.timezone()` still cannot return `UTC`.

Comment: Reference : Details in `?timezones`.